# Unexpected behaviour when redirecting stdout when using md5sum in bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection, md5sum

I was playing around with md5sum and redirections and I got a weird outcome.

I created an empty file name f1, and got this as its md5sum: `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  f1`.

Then I used the command `md5sum f1 > f1`, and as I expected it, when I use `cat f1`, the same result appears on screen.

Keeping on, trying to set a loop, I then used `md5sum f1`, and the result was `1e3c66dfc03fbebc883b4718bf1bb065  f1` (so I'm sure I'm not in a special case where f(x)=x).

So I then typed `md5sum f1 > f1`, and when I used cat on the file, the content didn't change a bit (it was still `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  f1` and not `1e3c66dfc03fbebc883b4718bf1bb065  f1` as it should be). So I thought that I was missing something with feed redirection (I'd like to point I'm not trying to have successives sums in the file, but only the last one computed), so I tried `echo foobar > f1` and `cat f1` gave me the expected `foobar`.

Do you have any idea why the new md5sum isn't in the file?

If this can help, I'm running Ubuntu version 18.04.4 and md5sum version 8.28

Thanks

Comment: So based on the second answer of your link, I should use `md5sum f1 | sponge f1`.

Well, if you want to post your comment as an answer, I will accept it, as you enlighted me. Thanks

Comment: I think it's probably better to mark it a duplicate; this problem comes up in a wide variety of situations, but it's really the same core thing (i.e. how shell output redirection works) so I think it's better to have one *good* answer (/collection of answers) and just refer to that in the other situations it comes up.